# Angular image conditionally with or without anchor-tag

Tags: angular, conditional-statements, anchor

I have this situation in a component now:

```html
  <a [routerLink]="[pageUrl] | localize" *ngIf="pageUrl">
    <img />
  </a>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!pageUrl">
    <img />
  </ng-container>
```

Ofcourse the image-tag can be much more. The thing is: I don't want to repeat myself. Can I solve this with an ng-template or something like that, and how would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it can be done with ng-template for else conditioning as below

```
 <a [routerLink]="[pageUrl] | localize" *ngIf="pageUrl; else elseBlock">
    <img />
  </a>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Content for else block</ng-template>
```